# Seed model-table with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET Core app with EF Core and a local database server.

I want to seed the model with pure SQL queries, using the Visual Studio's SQL Server Object tool.

Basically, I wrote a New Query object in the SQL tool and wrote the SQL `insert`, but it always throws an error "Invalid column name 'my-values'".

Is there any way to do this or do I have to do it by LINQ?

This is my model table in the database

```
[Id]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Code]   NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
[Name]   NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
[IsTrue] BIT           DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Country] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

And the SQL script I'm trying to run:

```
INSERT INTO Country (Name, Code, IsTrue) 
VALUES ("Afghanistan", "AF", 0),
       ("Åland Islands", "AX", 0),
...
```

The error I get

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'Afghanistan'."

for all the lines. There is like 200 rows I want to insert at once.

Comment: varchar values must be put in a single quote in mssql server , Please try using only single quote : Ex : 'afganistan'    dont use "afganishtan"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**String literals** in T-SQL are delimited with **single quotes** - not double quotes. Try using:

```
INSERT INTO Country (Name, Code, IsTrue) 
VALUES ('Afghanistan', 'AF', 0),
       ('Åland Islands', 'AX', 0),
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, it worked. Also I had to make the insert statment for each of the value, because it doesn't allow to insert multiple values in one statment.

Comment: @rronaldr: SQL Server **2008** and higher does support multiple tuples after a `VALUES` keyword - which would mean you're using a ***really really*** old version of SQL Server - you should definitely upgrade!! (even SQL Server 2008 / 2008 R2 are **no longer supported** by Microsoft) ...